# React JS, Python Django Tutorial - infinite loop componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, sqlite

I'm following an online video tutorial on creating a CRUD full-stack app with React/Django/Sqlite, but I am running into an infinite loop when fetching any table data. The problem seems to be caused by componentDidUpdate, which is necessary for reloading the table after updating/deleting an entry.

Here's a sample code snippet below (links below):

```js
refreshList(){
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'employee')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>{
        this.setState({emps:data}); //<=?
    });
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.refreshList();
}

componentDidUpdate(){ //<=
    this.refreshList();
}
```

1. [Learn React JS, Python Django by Creating a Full-Stack Web App from Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5ygXQKF6M8)
2. [GitHub Source Code](https://github.com/ArtOfEngineer/DjangoReactJs)
3. [Problem Code Snippet](https://github.com/ArtOfEngineer/DjangoReactJs/blob/main/reacttut/my-app/src/Employee.js#L28)

Comment: `setState` triggers `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` triggers `setState`, you shouldn't do this

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial leading people astray, you hate to see it.

That function can have three parameters `prevProps`, `prevState` and `snapshot`.
You can use those to check if the data was *actually* updated, if not skip the refresh if it wasn't.

This is the general format you want:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.emps !== this.state.emps) {
    this.refreshList();
  }
}
```

Check out this: https://dev.to/cesareferrari/how-to-use-componentdidupdate-in-react-30en
Here are the Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate